# The state of checkbox looks updated, but it is not updated actually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have strange issue. I am developing something for Magento. I added link "Select all categories" and add a jQuery event to check all checkboxes when I click on it. It works great, but somehow the html is not updated and Magento can't see that all inputs are selected. But when I manually click on a checkbox, it updates html (I am looking at the console) and Magento save button works just fine.

How to resolve this issue? I am not sure what else should I do to perform updating html. It look like it works (checkboxes are selected), but please take a look at the console and html. Html must be updated.

I created jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWGEZ/)

Comment: can you please post your HTML and jQuery code ?

Comment: I created fiddle already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check all checkboxes, like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/hWGEZ/1/) .

Your `is(':checked')` IF statement seems wrong as it should be enclosed on an `.each()` so it applies to all checkboxes, try the more simple approach on the fiddle I linked.

Comment: That fiddle won't be there forever; if I were you, I'd post your code here for anyone else seeking this answer in the future.

Comment: @boban0987 Why does it need to change the html?  The html doesn't matter if it's for a form.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `prop('checked', true);` instead of `prop('checked', 'checked');` ?
That's what I see in all the examples.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was Magento issue. Magento doesn't use that form, it uses hidden input and collects selected checkboxes. Will upvote all answers anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like :

```
// custom jQuery added
jQuery(function() {
    var to_check = false;       
    jQuery(".select-all-categories").click(function(){
        if (!to_check)
            to_check = true;
        else
            to_check = false;

        jQuery("#banner-categories input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
            if (!to_check)      
                jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
            else  
                jQuery(this).attr("checked","checked");
        });          
        return false;
    });
});
```

Code can be optimized